# Java get string list from html with JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I need to get the **content** of the meta tag with the name "keywords" from a URL.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="cat,dog,woof,meow">
```

How can i do this with **JSoup**?

I have tried getting the element by class, then trying to get the content if the name was keywords, but had no luck:

```
String keywords = document.select("meta.[name=keywords]").get(0).attr("content");
```

I don't know what I'm doing when it comes to an element without an ID, the error given is pretty straightforward:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: String must not be empty
    at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.notEmpty(Validate.java:92)
    at org.jsoup.select.QueryParser.byClass(QueryParser.java:208)
    at org.jsoup.select.QueryParser.findElements(QueryParser.java:146)
    at org.jsoup.select.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:65)
    at org.jsoup.select.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:39)
    at org.jsoup.select.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:80)
    at org.jsoup.select.Selector.select(Selector.java:93)
    at org.jsoup.nodes.Element.select(Element.java:252)
```

Comment: @KickButtowski Yes but it doesn't apply to a tag with no ID so i figured i wouldn't share it.

Comment: at least post up more info so we can learn more and help you to solve your issue faster? if you have any error you should post it up too :)

Comment: could you please post up the error too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
document.select("meta.[name=keywords]")
```

to

```
document.select("meta[name=keywords]")
```

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax